# C# meetings system

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, input

I'm creating a form to hold information from "meetings". The user will fill out info regarding `title`, `location`, `startTime`, `endTime`, `notes`, and a `date`. What I am currently working on is the "save changes" button which will:

1. clear all the TextBoxes.
2. store the input in an array.
3. display only the `title` in the ListBox.
4. when the title is clicked on in the ListBox, the info stored in that array element re-populates in the appropriate TextBoxes should the user wish to make changes.

I have completed #1, #2 and #3 I would appreciate any help for #4. I've pasted the coding below for your viewing.

```
public partial class CalendarForm : Form
{
    int currentIndex;
    int arraySize = 0;
    Meeting[] meetingArray = new Meeting[100];

    public CalendarForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void saveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        meetingArray[arraySize] = new Meeting();
        meetingArray[arraySize].title = textBoxTitle.Text;
        meetingArray[arraySize].location = textBoxLocation.Text;
        meetingArray[arraySize].startTime = textBoxStartTime.Text;
        meetingArray[arraySize].endTime = textBoxEndTime.Text;
        meetingArray[arraySize].notes = notesTextBox.Text;
        currentIndex = arraySize;
        arraySize++;
        meetingListBox.Enabled = true;
        textBoxTitle.Text = "";
        textBoxLocation.Text = "";
        textBoxStartTime.Text = "";
        textBoxEndTime.Text = "";
        notesTextBox.Text = "";

       *edit* added these two lines which now add the title to the listBox
       meetingListBox.Items.Add(meetingArray[currentIndex].title);
        Controls.Add(meetingListBox);

    }
}

public class Meeting
{
    public string title;
    public string location;
    public string startTime;
    public string endTime;
    public string notes;
};
```

Comment: This is not a place where people actually write code for you, you need to show *what you have tried* and if you have any specific question/problem then you will get positive responses.

Comment: here is what I tried:   meetingListBox.Text = meetingArray[currentIndex].title;

Comment: Although the Homework tag is now obsolete, it would be appropriate for you to mention whether or not this is a homework assignment.

Comment: @Golf_pro90: ListBox is a control that displays a collection, so you need to `Add` your meetings to it's list of `Items`. Read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx). Of course, the better solution is to use databinding.

Comment: @MattBurland cool thanks Matt. The info you provided was quite valuable. Any guidance for #4 would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would refactor the class:

```
public partial class CalendarForm : Form
{
  private List<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

  public CalendarForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Meetings = new List<Meeting>();
  }

  private void saveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {     
    try 
    {       
      Meeting meeting = CreateMeeting();
      Meetings.Add(meeting);
      meetingListBox.Add(meeting);
    }
    catch
    {
      //Add proper error handling here
    }            
  }

  private Meeting CreateMeeting()
  {
    return new Meeting()
    {
      Title = textBoxTitle.Text,
      Location = textBoxLocation.Text
      StartTime = DateTime.Parse(textBoxStartTime.Text),
      EndTime = DateTime.Parse(textBoxEndTime.Text),
      Notes = notesTextBox.Text,
     };
   }
}

//As Matt Burland answered already:
private void meetingListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Meeting meeting = meetingListBox.SelectedItem as Meeting;
  if (meeting != null) 
  {
    textBoxTitle.Text = meeting.Title;
    //...etc for all your other text boxes.
  }
}

public class Meeting
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Location  { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartTime  { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndTime  { get; set; }
  public string Notes  { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Title; 
  }
}
```

I've made a number of changes, more notably the switch from an Array to a List<>. Lists are more flexible and provide better functionality. Unless you really really need to use arrays, I would stay away from them just to better safeguard against logic errors index out of bounds type issues.

Also, I personally believe that dates should be stored in the DateTime struct format, but that is again a matter of preference. Note that it would be prudent to sanitize/validate the inputs (especially the dates) before assigning it into the Meeting object.

The Meeting object now has properties instead of public fields. Properties are preferred in case you ever want to change how something is Get/Set.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you look up data binding and learn how to do this properly, but if you want a quick and dirty solution (although, in the end, you'll find it's a lot more work), I would do something like this:

```
private void saveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Meeting m = new Meeting();
    m.title = textBoxTitle.Text;
    m.location = textBoxLocation.Text;
    m.startTime = textBoxStartTime.Text;
    m.endTime = textBoxEndTime.Text;
    m.notes = notesTextBox.Text;
    meetingArray[arraySize] = m;
    currentIndex = arraySize;
    arraySize++;
    meetingListBox.Enabled = true;
    textBoxTitle.Text = "";
    textBoxLocation.Text = "";
    textBoxStartTime.Text = "";
    textBoxEndTime.Text = "";
    notesTextBox.Text = "";

    meetingListBox.Items.Add(m);
    //Controls.Add(meetingListBox);   // You don't need to keep adding the control every time!


}
```

Now in your `Meeting` class, I'd override `ToString()` to just return the title. The `ListBox` will just use the `ToString()` method of whatever you add to it by default.

To help with #4, you want to bind the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and then use the `SelectedItem` property, cast it back to a `Meeting` object (because it'll return an `Object`) and then use it to repopulate your various text boxes.

Something like:

```
private void meetingListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Meeting m = meetingListBox.SelectedItem as Meeting;
    if (m != null) 
    {
        textBoxTitle.Text = m.title;
        //...etc for all your other text boxes.
    }
}
```

Comment: Matt...thanks a bunch! your insight and knowledge has been very helpful :)